# Does $P(\min(X, Y) < t \wedge X < Y) = P(\min(X,Y) < t) \cdot P(X < Y)$ hold for exponentially distributed $X,Y$?

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim \text{EXP}(\lambda_1), Y \sim \text{EXP}(\lambda_2)$ be two independent exponentially distributed random variables.

Does $$P(\min(X,Y) < t \wedge X < Y) = P(\min(X, Y) < t) \cdot P(X < Y)$$ hold?

And therefore $P(\min(X,Y) < t \;|\; X < Y) = P(\min(X,Y) < t)$?

Intuitively it makes sense that the CDF of the minimum is independent of who wins the race i.e. $X < Y$ but I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: Edit: The set $A=\{X\wedge Y<t\wedge X<Y\}=\{X<t<Y\}$. This gives $P[X<t]P[Y>t]=(1-e^{-\lambda_1t})e^{-\lambda_2 t}$.  The set $\{X\wedge Y<t\}=\{Y<t,X\geq t\}\cup\{X<t,Y\geq t\}\cup \{Y<t,X<t\}$ and so $P[X\wedge Y<t]=P[Y<t]P[X\geq t] + P[Y\geq t]P[X<t] +P[X<t]P[Y<t]=1-e^{-\lambda_2t})e^{-\lambda_1 t} + (1-e^{-\lambda_1 t})e^{-\lambda_2t} +  (1-e^{-\lambda_1 t}) (1-e^{-\lambda_2 t}) = 1-e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)t}$. Finally, $P[X<Y]=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2+\lambda_2}$. Putting things together, seems to indicate that the answer to your question is NO

Comment: Well. actually $\{\min(X,Y)<t, X<Y)\}=\{X<t<Y\}\cup\{X<Y<t\}$, but otherwise ...